# Include only records having letters and ignore the ones having numbers in a column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The data contains a column 'product_name' with data type string. It has strings having letters, alphanumeric strings, and numeric strings. I want to exclude the numeric string records and include all others. Below is an example-

```
product_name
 cell phone
 Headphones
   12356
  ABC56TV
   2345
```

Expected Result-

```
product_name
 cell phone
 Headphones
  ABC56TV
```

How to fetch this result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `regexp_contains()`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not regexp_contains(product, '^[0-9]+$');
```

This matches something that is not all digits.